# Make UITableView looks like UIPopover (but without arrow) in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

[image] 
 Want to crete a UITableView that looks like this? How to do that in swift?

Answer (score 0):

In your xib or storyboard, select the tableview.

Under 'Attributes Inspector' you can find the setting 'Accessory' select none and the arrow symbol will disappear.

[image]